# Typescript with d3js with definitlyTyped

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, d3.js, typescript

So, its my first day with typescript.

I ran into some trouble with this code:

```
  var x: d3.scale.Ordinal = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, +this.params.width], .1)
            .domain(data.map(function (d) {
                return d.DayName;
            }));
```

i want x to be of type ordinal scale, but for some reason i get this error:

```
Generic type 'Ordinal<Domain, Range>' requires 2 type argument(s).
```

And sure enough in code for DefinitlyTyped i can see following :

```
 interface Ordinal<Domain extends { toString(): string }, Range> {
        (x: Domain): Range;

        domain(): Domain[];
        domain(values: Domain[]): Ordinal<Domain, Range>;

        range(): Range[];
        range(values: Range[]): Ordinal<Domain, Range>;

        rangePoints(interval: [number, number], padding?: number): Ordinal<Domain, number>;
        rangeRoundPoints(interval: [number, number], padding?: number): Ordinal<Domain, number>;

        rangeBands(interval: [number, number], padding?: number, outerPadding?: number): Ordinal<Domain, number>;
        rangeRoundBands(interval: [number, number], padding?: number, outerPadding?: number): Ordinal<Domain, number>;

        rangeBand(): number;
        rangeExtent(): [number, number];

        copy(): Ordinal<Domain, Range>;
    }
```

So Ordinal need to have 2 extra types, Domain and range, but i cant find anywhere their structure.

How do i solve this problem? Or have i misunderstood something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Domain** and **Range** are generic type arguments, they are placeholders for the types you need to provide rather than actual concrete types. **Domain** can be any type that has a **toString** method, and **Range** can apparently be any type you want.

Typings in the DefinitelyTyped repository generally have some tests to ensure the typings work as expected, and if you're trying to figure out how to use some typings properly a good first step is looking at those tests. Here's a relevant example from the [D3 tests](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3/d3-tests.ts):

```
var fill = d3.scale.ordinal<number, string>()
    .domain(d3.range(4))
    .range(["#000000", "#FFDD89", "#957244", "#F26223"]);
```

So I think this should work for you:

```
var x: d3.scale.Ordinal<string, number> = d3.scale.ordinal<string, number>()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, +this.params.width], .1)
        .domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.DayName;
        }));
```

Or you can just let the compiler deduce the type of the variable:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal<string, number>()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, +this.params.width], .1)
        .domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.DayName;
        }));
```

If you're unfamiliar with generic types in TypeScript, I suggest reading the [section on Generics](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#generics) in the TypeScript handbook.